# melt, not as.data.frame or rbind in R (basic ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several equal-length vectors of numbers, like

```
alpha <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
beta <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
gamma <- c(9, 10, 11, 12)
```

and I want to put these into a data frame or something with columns labelled alpha, beta, and gamma. Like

```
alpha | beta | gamma
1 | 5 | 9
2 | 6 | 10
3 | 7 | 11
4 | 8 | 12
```

which `qplot` should be able to read and separate out by `colour = labels`. `cbind` and `rbind` result in a matrix which `qplot` cannot read. And `c` lines up alpha beta and gamma, without labelling them as separate.

The `diamonds` data set displays what I'm after with `qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds, colour = color)` except I want to plot my shared-dimensional data against an index like `x=1:4`.

In regular `R` I would do `plot(alpha); points(beta); points(gamma)`.

Sorry for asking such a basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a data.frame, then `data.frame` will do that:

```
> data.frame(alpha, beta, gamma)
  alpha beta gamma
1     1    5     9
2     2    6    10
3     3    7    11
4     4    8    12
```

And this can be passed to the `qplot` or `ggplot`.

In the case of `qplot`, you don't need to create data.frame. Just calling with the variables is sufficient like this:

```
qplot(alpha, beta, colour=gamma)
```

And updated after the comment.

I'm still not sure what is desired, but this example may help:

```
> d <- data.frame(x=1:4, alpha, beta, gamma)
> d
  x alpha beta gamma
1 1     1    5     9
2 2     2    6    10
3 3     3    7    11
4 4     4    8    12

> d2 <- melt(d, id="x")
> d2
   x variable value
1  1    alpha     1
2  2    alpha     2
... snip ...
11 3    gamma    11
12 4    gamma    12

> qplot(d2$x, d2$value, colour=d2$variable, geom="line")

# same as

> ggplot(d2, aes(x, value, colour=variable)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response! That's not quite what I'm trying to do, I'd like to `qplot( data = that.data.frame, geom = "line", colour = names(that.data.frame) )` and get three lines, one for alpha one for beta one for gamma, coloured according to label. Apologies if that was unclear.

Comment: In other words, alpha beta gamma are all denoted in the same units and I just want the plots side-by-side. Kind of like the Diamonds dataset with `colour = color`.

Comment: @Lao Tzu I can not understand what you mean, but maybe `melt`int the data.frame is relevant. try `d <- data.frame(alpha, beta, gamma); d2 <- melt(d)`

Comment: If this explains it - I achieved what I want in regular `R` by doing `plot(alpha); points(beta); points(gamma)`. So I'm trying to achieve the same with `ggplot` by feeding in a data structure like `diamonds`.